# Where am I going wrong in calculating this truth table?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to find the truth table for the following problem and then find its equivalent statement.

$$(((!r\wedge (p\Leftrightarrow !p)\vee q)\Rightarrow p)$$

Steps I took:

First, I decided to try and break down the statement into smaller parts to make it easier to figure out so I made:

$$a=(p\Leftrightarrow !p)$$

$$b=((!r\wedge (p\Leftrightarrow !p))$$

$$c=(((!r\wedge (p\Leftrightarrow !p)\vee q))$$

$$d=(((!r\wedge (p\Leftrightarrow !p)\vee q)\Rightarrow p)$$

So, $$b=!r \wedge a$$

$$c=b \vee q$$

$$d=c\Leftrightarrow p$$

Here is a picture of the truth table I have constructed following those conditions:

[image]

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: You’ve gone astray with $b$: $\neg r\land(p\leftrightarrow\neg p)$ is always false, since $p\leftrightarrow\neg p$ is always false. That’s thrown everything else off. $c$ should actually be a copy of $q$.

Comment: Oh. I think I see it now. $F\wedge F$ is still $F$. So all of $b$ should be false. Right?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. $F\land X$ is $F$ no matter what $X$ is.

Comment: So I changed it now. $c$ did indeed become a copy of $q$, but what does $d$ become equivalent to? I got $d=T,T,F,T,T,T,F,T$

Comment: That’s correct: $d$ is just $q\to p$, so the only way for it to be false is for $q$ to be true and $p$ false.

Comment: well I thought $d=c\Rightarrow p$, but you're saying the equivalent statement of that entire statement I started out with is $q\Rightarrow p$? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: $d$ is indeed $c\to p$, but $c$ turns out to be exactly equivalent to $q$, so $d$ is exactly equivalent to $q\to p$. (By *exactly equivalent* I mean that they have the same truth table.) Your original expression is equivalent to $q\to p$.

Comment: So, just to recap:

$d=c\Rightarrow p$, and $c\equiv q$; therefore, $d\equiv q\Rightarrow p$.

Finally, $(((!r\wedge (p\Leftrightarrow !p)\vee q)\Rightarrow p)\equiv q\Rightarrow p$

Let me know if I used the proper notation, please.

Comment: Looks fine, though I would use $\neg$, $\leftrightarrow$, and $\to$ where you have $!$, $\Leftrightarrow$, and $\Rightarrow$.

Comment: I know the $!$ is not the right notation. I just don't know how to type that up. But, why do I have to use the iff and implies symbols that you specified. How are they different from the ones I used?

Comment: You get $\neg$ with `\neg`. In my usage, which is pretty common, the single-arrow forms are propositional connectives (like $\land$ and $\lor$), and the double-arrow forms are used to express the notion of entailment between propositions, just as $\equiv$ does. It’s a subtle difference that doesn’t matter very much at this level. Suppose that $a$ and $b$ are two propositions. Then $a\to b$ is another proposition, while $a\Rightarrow b$ is a statement *about* the propositions $a$ and $b$, namely, that if $a$ is true, then so is $b$, or from $a$ one can legitimately infer $b$.

Comment: But, doesn't $a\rightarrow b$ still mean that $a$ implies $b$?

Comment: No, $a\to b$ is simply a propositional statement that has truth values dependent on those of the propositional variables appearing in it. $a\Rightarrow b$ is the statement that whenever $a$ has the truth value $T$, so does $b$. It is then a theorem *about* (not *in*) propositional logic that $a\Rightarrow b$ if and only if $a\to b$ is a tautology.

Comment: To be honest, you're using esoteric terms right now that are quite intimidating to a layman like me. I want to understand, but I'm nowhere near that good or knowledgeable in math. I'm just a first year computer science student who enjoys doing math. 

Would you be able to explain it in layman terms?

Comment: Think of a propositional statement (like $p\to(q\lor r)$) as a function; its input is a string of truth values ($T$ or $F$), one for each propositional variable, so that in the example it could be something like $\langle F,F,T\rangle$, meaning that we’re inputting $F$ for $p$, $F$ for $q$, and $T$ for $r$. Its output is then the truth value of the statement; in this example that would be $T$ for this input. If $a$ and $b$ are propositional statements, then $a\to b$ is another propositional statement: it’s a new function that takes lists of truth values to truth values, built from the old ...

Comment: ... functions $a$ and $b$. In contrast, $a\Rightarrow b$ is a statement *about* the functions $a$ and $b$. It says that any input that causes $a$ to produce the output $T$ will also cause $b$ to produce the output $T$. And we can prove that this is the case if and only if the truth value function $a\to b$ is a tautology, meaning that it produces the output $T$ for every input.

Comment: So, in short $a\rightarrow b$ just refers to the output (truth value) of that statement, whereas, $a\Rightarrow b$ refers to the implication $a$ has on $b$?

Comment: Close; it would be better, I think, especially for someone with a comp. sci. background, to think of $a\to b$ as a function from (lists of) truth values to truth values, and $a\Rightarrow b$ as a statement about the relationship between two such functions.

Comment: That last explanation did it for me! Please add some of the main points you told me below as an answer and I will accept it an +1

Comment: Excellent! Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve gone astray with $b$: $\neg r\land(p\leftrightarrow\neg p)$ is always false, since $p\leftrightarrow\neg p$ is always false. That’s thrown everything else off. First, $c$ should be a copy of $q$: $c$ is logically equivalent to the simple proposition $q$, true when $q$ is true and false when $q$ is false. This means that the original expression $d$ is logically equivalent to $q\to p$, so you should have $F$ only in the third and seventh lines.

I’ll add a comment on your notation, specifically, the use of the double arrows $\Leftrightarrow$ and $\Rightarrow$ where I would use single arrows, $\leftrightarrow$ and $\to$. I use the latter for logical connectives (on a par with $\neg,\land$, and $\lor$) used to build compound propositions and reserve the former for statements *about* propositions. (Some people do use the double arrow forms for logical connectives, but I think that my convention is more common.)

The difference is a bit subtle. Think of propositions as functions. A proposition that combines $n$ proposition letters (using $\neg,\land,\lor,\to$, and $\leftrightarrow$, for instance) is a function from the set of $n$-tuples of truth values to the set $\{T,F\}$ of truth values. For instance, the proposition $p\to(q\lor r)$ is a function from the set of ordered triples of truth values to the set of truth values. It takes inputs like $\langle F,F,T\rangle$, assigns the first input to $p$, the second to $q$, and the third to $r$, and produces as output the truth value of the expression $p\to(q\lor r)$, which in this case is $T$. Thus, $\to$ and $\leftrightarrow$ are ways of combining two such functions to get a third.

The double arrow symbols are statements *about* these functions. For instance, $a\Rightarrow b$ means that every input of truth values that makes $a$ true also makes $b$ true. It is not itself a function from truth values to truth values: it’s a statement about the relationship between two such functions. However, there’s a close relationship between $a\Rightarrow b$ and $a\to b$: it’s a theorem of logic that $a\Rightarrow b$ is true if and only if $a\to b$ is a tautology, meaning that it’s a truth value function whose output is *always* $T$. Similarly, $a\Leftrightarrow b$ means that the inputs that make $a$ true are identical to the inputs that make $b$ true; many people express this by the notation $a\equiv b$ instead. And it’s a theorem of logic that $a\Leftrightarrow b$ is true if and only if $a\leftrightarrow b$ is a tautology.